# How to save a PDF file created in my app to iBooks with UIActivityViewController?

Tags: swift, ios9, xcode7, uiactivityviewcontroller, ibooks

I am creating a **pdf** in my ios9 app and would like to be able to save it to iBooks with the UIActivityViewController. Unfortunately, with the code I'm currently using (assuming that all options using :

```
   applicationActivities: nil
```

for what I can do with the file will show up) only the "Message" and "Mail" items show up. I'm not excluding any activities, so hypothetically UIActivityTypeOpenInIBooks should show up just fine. However, I can't get iBooks or anything but Message and Mail show up. (For future reference I will refer to this outcome as outcome **A** ) Is there another recommended way of doing this?
The code I'm using is below:

```
  // creating pdf image from the UIView
  let pdf = self.getPDFImageFromDrawingView()

  let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [pdf], applicationActivities: nil) //should include any and all available activities right?

  self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Is there something obvious I'm forgetting? How do you include iBooks as an option for saving files?

**EDIT :**

In debugging this issue, I've saved the UIView content as a JPG AND as a pdf file. When I use ONLY the generated UIImage as such:

**(outcome B)**

```
    let image = self.getUIImageFromDrawingView() // generate a UIImage object
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image], applicationActivities: nil)
    self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

all the possible options show up, including open in iBooks (YES! But I need the much-higher resolution image generated by creating a PDF.)

When I add **BOTH the image and the pdf** to the activityItems (as such:

**(outcome C)**

```
let image = self.getUIImageFromDrawingView() // UIImage
let pdf = self.getPDFImageFromDrawingView() //produces an NSData object
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image, pdf], applicationActivities:nil)
```

), I get more options then the original mail and message options - like FB, Pinterest and Evernote - but no iBooks.

Finally, when I go back to using only the PDF, I have the same things as before - only mail and messages. What could be causing this? 
(BTW, interesting if not useless aside - when using both the JPG and the PDF, and testing the applicationActivities with Mail - I get the email of a jpg and a pdf, as expected. So the files are being generated as expected).

What could be causing this weird behavior?

**EDIT 2 :**

I Thought that may be the problem was that I was using NSData to send the pdf. So, I saved the object as an NSURL and used that. I got the same result as in **(C)** above - more options then just Messages and Mail, but no iBooks. This outcome came with using both the UIImage + NSURL combination, AND when using NSURL alone. When I used UIImage alone, I had many many options, as in the previous situation, including iBooks.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this every which way, and couldn't get it to work with the UIActivityController.
However, it worked like a charm when I used the UIDocumentInteractionController:

```
    let pdfData = self.getPDFasNSData() // get the NSData object
    let fileURL = self.getCurrentPDFURLName() //get the NSURL 

    self.docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: fileURL)

    if (fileURL != nil)
    {
        pdfData.writeToURL(fileURL, atomically: true);         
        self.docController.presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem(self.organizeBarButton, animated: true)
     }
```

Now the "open in iBooks" option shows up.